# Python IndentationError at if

Tags: python

Here's the code

```
def properties(imgnum):
    ...
    if imgnum == 6:
        bonus = 0
        #img6.gif
        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './Images/img6.gif')
        root.geometry("450x450")
        root.update()
        canvas.create_image(225,225, image=photo)
        root.mainloop()
        props = {...}
    if imgnum == 7:
        bonus = 0
        #img7.gif
        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './Images/img7.gif')
        root.geometry("450x450")
        root.update()
        canvas.create_image(225,225, image=photo)
        root.mainloop()
        props = {}
    if imgnum == 8:
        bonus = 0
        #img8.gif
        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './Images/img8.gif')
        root.geometry("450x450")
        root.update()
        canvas.create_image(225,225, image=photo)
        root.mainloop()
        props = {}
```

and here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop\Eoy\EOY.py", line 1, in <module>
    from EOY_props import properties
  File "C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop\Eoy\EOY_props.py", line 55
    if imgnum == 7:
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I've heard that this is from mixing tabs and spaces which i did not do.
all the code is even with the other code, all parentheses and brackets are closed.
the props dictionary is on the to do list, this is all a work in progress.

Comment: it might have something to do with the code between your `if` statement and your method declaration. could you post that code as well?

Comment: What does the code above `if imgnum == 7:` look like? That error usually means that the indentation level of `if imgnum...` is incorrect based on what came before it. In this case it looks like it's expecting `if imgnum == 7` to be indented more based on the previous line.

Comment: There's more to props{...} than given here. Try replacing it with `props = {}` and see if you have the same problem. Add an indented statement right after props and a dedented statement right before the if as sentinals.

Comment: mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: Not related to your question at all, but you could rewrite that as a single block like `photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='./Images/img%d.gif' % imagenum)` so that you don't have to hard-code a bunch of identical lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem has been figured out:
IDLE was not saving the file when i was hitting ctrl+s
compiler didn't detect anything under the statement because there wasn't anything